# calling an external program in c doesn't seem to work (error with spaces)

Tags: c

When i write this code:

```
if(number==5) {
    system("start c:\\geek.exe");
}
```

everything works fine cause there are no spaces in the path.
But when i write something like this:

```
if(number==8) {
    system("start C:\\program files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe");
}
```

I get a message that it doesn't find the path.

Comment: `"start C:\\program files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe"` should be `"start \"C:\\program files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe\""`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use double quotes:-

```
system("start \"C:\\program files\\...\");
```

Comment: this opens a new prompt under the path where i save my .c files. so it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the right way:

```
if(number==8) {
    system("\"C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe\"");
}
```